# Python openpyxl - want to protect a sheet but allow filtering, sorting on all cols, and allow editing on column "D"

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

i have an excel file that I want to protect but also want to allow

- filtering on all cols
- sorting on all cols
- EDITING of all cells in column "D" (preferably D2 to end (to preserve the heading in D1)

I have gotten this far.

this executes and works to a degree, in that the sheet is now protected.

But ...
The filters "exist" but don't work (can't click on them)
Sort doesn't work
Column D is still not editable

Hoping for some guidance on this.

using python 3.9 and openpyxl 3.0.10

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles.protection import Protection

# open wb
wb = load_workbook("test2.xlsx")

# select sheet1
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

# protect sheet
ws.protection.enabled = True
ws.protection.password = 'password'

# allow filtering on all cols
ws.auto_filter.ref = "A1:H1"
ws.auto_filter.enable = True

# allow editing on all cells in col D
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        cell.protection = Protection(locked=(cell.column != "D"))

# save to new file
wb.save("test9.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added into your code the individual protections that can be set on the sheet. The state of each is set to what is expected when executing

```
ws.protection.enabled = True
```

except for those marked as changed.
Re-enabling the 'autofilter' is easy enough, just set `.autoFilter` back to False

```
.autoFilter = False
```

This allows the filters to be selected.
There is a `sort` setting

```
.sort = False
```

but changing that back to `False` does not enable sorting. The best I can determine is you cannot just re-enable sorting by changing the protection setting, the following is from a Microsoft help site;
 ***You can't sort locked cells on a protected sheet. You have to either unlock the cells, or unprotect, sort, and then reprotect.***

I also changed the loop to set column D lock protection off for row 2 to last used row. Editing column D works excluding the Header and cells below 'row max'. If you want more rows than the 'used range' to be editable in column D you can set a `max_row` value in the `iter_rows`.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles.protection import Protection

# open wb
wb = load_workbook("test2.xlsx")

# select sheet1
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

# allow editing on all cells in col D
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, min_col=4, max_col=4):
    for cell in row:
        cell.protection = Protection(locked=False)
        print(cell.protection.locked)

### protect sheet
ws.protection.enabled = True
ws.protection.password = 'password'

### All individual sheet protections set per 'protection.enabled = True'
### Except those marked as 'Changed'
prot = ws.protection
prot.selectLockedCells = False
prot.selectUnlockedCells = False
prot.algorithmName = None
prot.sheet = True
prot.objects = False
prot.insertRows = True
prot.insertHyperlinks = True
prot.autoFilter = False  # Changed
prot.scenarios = False
prot.formatColumns = True
prot.deleteColumns = True
prot.insertColumns = True
prot.pivotTables = True
prot.deleteRows = True
prot.formatCells = True
prot.saltValue = None
prot.formatRows = True
prot.sort = False  # Changed
prot.spinCount = None
prot.hashValue = None


# allow filtering on all cols
ws.auto_filter.ref = "A1:H1"
ws.auto_filter.enable = True

# save to new file
wb.save("test9.xlsx")
```

Comment: Cheers mate that's terrific, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use xlsxwriter to sort and filter the columns and rows after unlocking all the cells in a password-protected sheet. Update the code to set column D lock protection off for row 2 to last used row.

```
import openpyxl
import xlsxwriter

# Load the workbook and sheet
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:/Users/xyz/Downloads/DEMO_I.xlsx")
sheet = workbook["DEMO_I"]

# Create a new Excel workbook and worksheet using XlsxWriter
output_file = "C:/Users/xyz/Downloads/DEMO_I_protected.xlsx"
workbook_xlsx = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output_file)
worksheet_xlsx = workbook_xlsx.add_worksheet()

# Copy data from existing worksheet to new worksheet
for row_num, row in enumerate(sheet.iter_rows(values_only=True), start=1):
    for col_num, value in enumerate(row, start=1):
        worksheet_xlsx.write(row_num - 1, col_num - 1, value)

# Set unlocked format for all cells
unlocked_format = workbook_xlsx.add_format({'locked': False})
worksheet_xlsx.protect("1234", options={'format_columns': True, 'autofilter': True, 'sort': True,
                   'select_locked_cells':False,'select_unlocked_cells':False,'delete_columns':False,
                   'insert_columns':False,'delete_rows':False,'format_cells':False,'format_rows':False})

# Apply autofilter to all columns
num_rows = sheet.max_row
num_cols = sheet.max_column
worksheet_xlsx.autofilter(0, 0, num_rows - 1, num_cols - 1)

# Apply sort to all columns
worksheet_xlsx.unprotect_range('A1:D12', 'MyRange')

# Save the XlsxWriter workbook
workbook_xlsx.close()
```