# how can i locked the specific columns in excel using openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have tried to lock some specific columns or cell in excel but i couldnt. My code isn't working. it doesnt returns any error but it isnt working. i cant understand. i had reviewed the same problems which is in the stackoverflow before i wrote it here. But any solution didnt working. i want to lock some specific cell or column in excel.

```
 def locked_cells(self, excel_file_path):
    wb = load_workbook(excel_file_path)

    ws = wb["Sheet1"]

    ws.protection.enable()
    ws.protection.sort = False

    ws.protection.sheet = True

        for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=ws.max_row, min_col=1, max_col=1):
            for cell in row:
                cell.protection = Protection(locked=True)
```

Comment: define *My code isn't working.*

Comment: it does not return an error message but there is no change in excel. So neither the whole sheet nor some specific columns are locked. Although the locking process does not give an error, it does not work.

Comment: It definitely does something. Are you saving the workbook at the end?

Comment: thanks for your answer. it helps to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enable protection by whatever means like

```
ws.protection.enable()
```

you have enabled protection on the cells in the sheet. Therefore assuming you haven't changed the lock protection on any cell prior, when you execute this line then every cell on the sheet is protected, i.e. you cannot edit cells and the other protections are applied or not depending on their default setting if not changed prior.
However nothing will be applied until you **save the workbook** which is the only reason I can think your code sample *isn't working*.

By default every cell state is 'locked' so running this loop probably does nothing

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=ws.max_row, min_col=1, max_col=1):
    for cell in row:
        cell.protection = Protection(locked=True)
```

you are just setting the state that is already set.
If you wanted to protect the sheet but leave cell 'A1' free to edit then you must set it to `Protection(locked=False)` then when you enable the protection all cells are locked for editing except cell 'A1'.

You have included `ws.protection.sort` setting in your example so you may want to review this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75090373/13664137) regarding sorting a protected sheet.